# I am trying to use react-simple-nav in my project but unexpectedly does not show up. Someone, could say what I am missing here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All my code is below, showing that I am doing everything as needed to render a correct sidebar but it not happening in my code...

If I go to components tree it is possible to see it but it is not rendering... [The result is that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmSjn.png)

***Update:***
If I set the initial state of showNav to true, show the sidebar but no show the menu icon... I needed to see the menu icon to open the sidebar when I want.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "childmiles",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-simple-sidenav": "^1.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my Main component, where I call the sidebar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import SideBar from './SideBarComponent';

class Main extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <SideBar/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

This is the sideBar itself:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideNav, {MenuIcon} from 'react-simple-sidenav';

export default class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showNav : false
        };
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <MenuIcon onClick={() => this.setState({showNav: true})}/>

                <SideNav
                    showNav = {this.state.showNav}
                    onHideNav = {() => this.setState({showNav: false})}
                    title          =  "Hello World"
                    items          =  {['home', 'services', 'about', 'contact']}
                    titleStyle     =  {{backgroundColor: '#4CAF50'}}
                    itemStyle      =  {{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
                    itemHoverStyle =  {{backgroundColor: '#CDDC39'}} />
            </div>
            )
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, I thought it has not been rendered and something went wrong but that's not the case.

Just tested out your code and it works like charm for me, the hamburger menu showed up, once I clicked, it represented the side menu. The issue is, the icon is not visible in a white background so what I did, added for testing purposes a blue background-color for the `div` as the following:

```
render() {
    return <div className="bg">
        <MenuIcon onClick={() => this.setState({showNav: true})}/>

        <SideNav
            showNav = {this.state.showNav}
            onHideNav = {() => this.setState({showNav: false})}
            title          =  "Hello World"
            items          =  {['home', 'services', 'about', 'contact']}
            titleStyle     =  {{backgroundColor: '#4CAF50'}}
            itemStyle      =  {{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
            itemHoverStyle =  {{backgroundColor: '#CDDC39'}} />
    </div>
}
```

In `CSS` file:

```
.bg {  
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Representation:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you try to inspect the div element and find inside the `MenuIcon`? If you find that there, try to click it, I still think it is just a `CSS` issue. Or maybe change it from `MenuIcon` to `<div onClick={() => this.setState({showNav: true})}>click me</div>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As my reputation is low, I could not make a comment. Could it be that you are missing the CSS for the component?

1. Try including the CSS if any
2. Ensure that onClick method of Menu Icon is triggered
3. Check the this keyword in onClick method of Menu Icon component